# Problem regarding Trapezium.

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

Suppose ABCD is a trapezium whose sides and height are integers and AB is parallel to CD. If the area of ABCD is $12$ and the sides are distinct, then $|AB – CD|  = 4$.

Can anyone please help me by giving some hints?

Comment: I have no idea how to proceed? I am looking for a small hint ...@TheDemonix_Hermit

Comment: No no I just have to prove that $|AB -CD| =4$..

Comment: **Note :** If we take $AE$ to be the height  , then $AE \cdot (AB+CD) = 24$ and we know that $AE,AB,CD$ are positive integers.

Comment: Up to that anyone can do..@TheDemonix_Hermit

Comment: When you say the sides are integers, do you mean the slanting sides $AC,BD$ are integers, or that all four sides are integers. The configuration looks impossible in the second case.

Comment: All sides are integer..@almagest

Answer (score 2):

Consider a trapezium ABCD whose one vertex A is in the origin $~(0,0)~$. Given that AB is parallel to CD and the sides are distinct so let the coordinate of B, D and C are respectively $(a,0),~(0,h)~$and$~(b,h)$.

[image]

So $~\overline{AB}=a,~\overline{AD}=h,~\overline{BC}=b~$and$~\overline{CB}=\sqrt{(b-a)^2+h^2~}$.

By the question $~\overline{AB},~\overline{AD},~\overline{DC},~\overline{BC}~$are all  integers.

**We have to show that$~|AB – CD|  = 4~$i.e., $~|a-b|=4~$**

Tthe area of ABCD,
$$= \frac{1}{2} × \text{Sum of parallel sides $×$ Height} = \frac{1}{2} × (\overline{AB} + \overline{DC}) × \overline{AD}= \frac{1}{2} × (a + b) × h$$
Given that $$\frac{1}{2} × (a + b) × h=12$$
$$\implies (a+b)h=24\tag1$$
The possible values of $~a,~b,~h~$ that satisfies equation $(1)$ and also the condition that $\overline{CB}=\sqrt{(b-a)^2+h^2~}$ is integer are either $~h=3,~a=6,~b=2~$ or,$~h=3,~a=2,~b=6~$.

Hence $~|a-b|=|6-2|=4~.$